# How to draw stacks of blocks in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am preparing a presentation on Python Scientific Computing and trying to draw a block diagram showing the software stack that are used in this environment. I came up with a good output, but since I am not expert in tikz, I am consulting you to guide me to the best way to do that.

One of the drawbacks of my method is that any changes in one block (more text) will enlarge this block and have to change other block measurements.  My question is there any way to do this kind of figure more easily.

If there is no other way, could you please look to my code, and guide me to somethings that I miss and should use in drawing such figure.

Thanks & Regards
Abdullah

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri}

\begin{document}



\tikzstyle{basics}=[rectangle, fill=red!20, node distance = 0, 
                  minimum height=1cm, minimum width=6.05cm,
                 ]
\tikzstyle{numpy}=[rectangle, fill=red!20, node distance = 0, 
                  minimum height=1cm, minimum width=4cm,
                 ]                 
\tikzstyle{upper}=[rectangle,
                   fill = green!10, node distance = 0,
                   minimum height=0.7cm,
                   minimum width=2cm,
                   ]

\tikzstyle{background}=[rectangle,
                                                fill=gray!15,
                                                inner sep=0.5cm,
                                                rounded corners=5mm]

\tikzstyle{sympi}=[rectangle,
                   fill= green!30, node distance=0,
                   minimum height= 1.7cm, minimum width = 1cm,
                    ]                                               
\centering                                                
\begin{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (python) [basics] {Python Core} ;
\node (numpy) [ numpy, fill = blue!20, above=of python.north west, anchor=south west] {Numpy} ;
\node (scipy) [upper, align=center, above=of numpy.north west, anchor=south west] {Scipy lib};
\node (Pandas) [upper, right=of scipy] {Pandas};
\node (Sympi) [sympi,right=of Pandas.north east,  anchor=north west]
 {\rotatebox{90}{Sympi}};
\node (Matplotlib) [sympi,right=of Sympi]
  {\rotatebox{90}{{\footnotesize Matplotlib}}};
\node (ipython) [node distance = 0.2, below=of python  ] {IPython Interactive Computing};

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \node [background,
                    fit=(python) (numpy) (scipy) (Pandas) (Sympi) (ipython),
                   label=above:Python Scientific Enviroment ] {};

    \end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Abdullah, welcome to the site. Are these the only text blocks you will use or you plan to add more content later once this is figured out?

Comment: That's for now. It is work in progress. I may add more later. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz,preview]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds,positioning,fit}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 0mm,
block/.style args = {#1,#2}{fill=#1,
                            text width=#2,
    shape=rectangle, draw=gray!30, thick,
    minimum height=11mm, align=center, 
    inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm}
                        ]    
\node[block={red!20,60mm},
      label=below:IPython Interactive Computing]              
                                        (python)    {Python Core};
\node[block={blue!20,38mm}, 
      above right=of python.north west] (numpy)     {Numpy} ;
\node[block={green!20,19mm},
      above right=of numpy.north west]  (scipy)     {Scipy lib};
\node[block={green!20,19mm},
      right=of scipy]        (pandas)    {Pandas};
\path   let \p1 = (numpy.south west),
            \p2 = (scipy.north west),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)} in 
    node[block={green!30,11mm},minimum height=\n1,
         above right=of numpy.south east]  
                            (simpy)     {\rotatebox{90}{Sympi}}
    node[block={green!30,11mm},minimum height=\n1,
         right=of simpy]    (matlib)    {\rotatebox{90}{Matplotlib}};
\scoped[on background layer]
\node[rounded corners=5mm,fill=gray!30,
      inner sep=4mm,yshift=-2mm,
      label=above:Python Scientific Enviroment,
      fit=(python) (scipy)]             {};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

which gives:
[image]

The colors probably are not as you wish, but this is minor problem and thay can be easily adopted to your wish.

As you can see, main difference between yours and mine MWE is in presets. Instead preset a shape for each node, I use only one ("generic") with two optional parameters, which I change at each it use. Optional parameters are fill color and text width of node.

Another "trick" is use `calc` library for calculation of height of upper right nodes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. It is very helpful. I appreciate it.

Comment: I got a compilation error on \scoped[on background layer]. It gives me undefined control sequence \scoped. I solved the problem by using \begin{scope}[on background layer] instead.

Comment: @Abdullah, at me work as should. Differences can be in fact, that I have installed quit recent CVS version of TikZ .